# camel jdbc out of memory exception

Tags: apache-camel, camel-jdbc

I am trying to ingest data from postgres to another DB and I am using camel-jdbc component to do it. I have a large table so I want to read few rows at a time instead of the whole table altogether. so my route looks like below (only for testing purpose) 
from(fromUri).setBody("select * from table limit 10").to("jdbc://myDataSource?resetAutoCommit=false&statement.fetchSize=2").split(body()).streaming().process(test)

As shown above, I am only getting 10 rows at a time for testing purpose and I have set fetchSize to 2 to only receive 2 rows at a time. However, I am still receiving all 10 rows altogether. When I remove the "limit 10" from the query I get Out of Memory error just before the split command which tells me that its trying to load the entire result set in memory.

What am I missing here or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think fetchSize is more of a hint to the JDBC driver. You can use the maxRows option to really limit on the server side, eg `statement.maxRows=2`. You can read more about these options on the JDBC javadoc documentation.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html

Comment: statement.maxRows=2 doesnt really work. all it does is it returns only 2 rows and discards the remaining 8 rows which is not what I want.

Comment: Set outputType=StreamList in the Camel JDBC uri and read the documentation: http://camel.apache.org/jdbc

Comment: I already tried that. Thats where I originally started where my route looked like from(fromUri).setBody(select * from table).to("jdbc://myDataSource?outputType=StreamList).split(body()).streaming().process(test). The above route doesnt event get to process as its trying to load all the data from table in memory and throws out of memory error before splitting the body.

Comment: @Pri Did you manage to overcome this problem? I am facing a similar situation.