# Camel JDBC StreamList query appears to load whole resultset before splitting

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, apache-camel

I'm running a SQL consumer to read changes from a table, which is all well and good. However, there are occasions where changes happen on mass, and then my query breaks with out of memory error, as you might expect.

Unfortunately, I'm stuck on Camel 2.17.6, so the StreamList option for the SQL component isn't available. (Although according to [Camel-SQL Why using StreamList seems to load all ResultSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52200896/camel-sql-why-using-streamlist-seems-to-load-all-resultset) this doesn't work as a stream list due to Spring JDBC limitations.)

So I've re-written my route using the JDBC component, which supports a stream list, and I'm still getting out of memory exceptions as soon as I increase the number of records to extract. It would appear that for some reason, the JDBC component is trying to extract all the records before passing to the splitter.

What I have now is of the form:

```
from("timer:timer...")
  .to( "language:constant:resource:classpath:pathToSqlStatement/sqlStatement.sql" )
  .to( "jdbc:msSqlServerDataSource?outputType=StreamList" )
  .split( body() ).streaming()
  .setBody().simple("$body[XMLDOC]")
  .setHeader("HeaderName").xpath("xpath/to/data")
  .to("jms:topic:name");
```

I did originally have an aggregation strategy `UseLatestAggregationStrategy` and an extra step after the `split()` but I've stripped that out in an attempt to remove everything that could possibly result in the whole query being held in memory, but I can't see what else I can do now.

I note the question [camel jdbc out of memory exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395970/camel-jdbc-out-of-memory-exception) raises a similar problem, and didn't appear to have a resolution.

(I should note that the out of memory errors I've had do appear in different places, and included `GC overhead limit exceeded` at `WinNTFileSystem` which I don't understand, and something else to do with a ZippedInputStream, which again I don't understand.)

Does that mean that StreamList doesn't work on the JDBC component either, or do I have to do something specific to ensure that the JDBC component doesn't try to cache the whole results?

Answer (score 0):

`StreamList` output type is supported in camel-sql since version v.18.x. In earlier version, camel-sql component load the [result set in memory as list](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/6f2767b2e88ba74860923650fc5c66888498ecff/components/camel-sql/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/sql/SqlConsumer.java#L121). I don't think it can be avoided in camel-sql version 2.17.x.

Aggregation /splitting does apply after loading the result in memory by camel-sql component.

[Another related answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53966933/1700467)

Comment: Hi @skadya! Thanks - as I said in my question, I realised `StreamList` isn't in 2.17.x so recast the route to use camel-jdbc which supported `StreamList` from 2.14 according to the manual.

Comment: Interestingly, I've just tested in a higher version, and while the Camel JDBC component still doesn't stream the query. However, the 2.20 SQL component does work as I'd expect with a StreamList! However, for now I'm stuck on 2.17, so that doesn't help much until I can get the server upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with postgres, but putting transacted in front of the jdbc query resolved my issue.

The cause of the problem is that with postgres, the autocommit flag must be false to get streamed result. The only way of doing that, within the camel route, seemed to be putting transacted in front of the call.